# Why isn't 18:9 ratio just called 2:1?

Tags: screen

Two of the most common screen ratios are `4:3` and `16:9`. `4:3` could have just been called `16:12`, but I guess how it works is that they always round down without decimal point, which explains why `16:9` isn't called `8:4.5`. Why isn't this the case with `18:9`?

Answer (score 2):

Um, basically because people are used to hearing "16:9" and 18:9 has two more on one side than 16. So from a marketing standpoint, it's 16:9 ... but two bigger.

In short, "Most blokes, you know, will be viewing at 16. Where can you go from there? 18. Two bigger."

...These go to 18.